# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended - Create View

Tags: sql, oracle, cloud

Getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in the following code which I am using in Oracle Cloud.

```
    create view yss_enrollments as select 
    d.sid,
    d.coll_code,
    d.citizenship,
    f.term_code,
    f.sfrstcr_ptrm_code,
    f.sid,
    f.scbcrse_subj_code,
    f.scbcrse_crse_numb,
    f.CRN,
    f.scbcrse_title,
    f.credit
from
    ADMIN.enrollments_dim.sid d, ADMIN.enrollments_facts.sid f
where d.sid = f.sid
;
```

Thoughts?
Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 1):

Both "tables" in the `from` clause seem to be wrong, e.g.

```
ADMIN.enrollments_dim.sid
```

What is what, here? Syntax says that you can use "owner"."table name". Presuming `admin` is the owner (schema) of the `enrollments_dim` table, what would `sid` then be?